# Why the tkinter program is not showing any text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to add some text in the frame but in the output I am getting a frame only.

The program is not showing any text in the frame in the output.
Can anyone help me out?

code -

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("730x544")
f1 = Frame(root, bg="grey", borderwidth="6", relief=SUNKEN)
f1.pack(side=LEFT)
label_f1 = Label(f1, text="File\n\nEdit\n\nSelection\n\nTerminal\n\nHelp",
font="comicsansms 7 bold",
fg="white")
label_f1.pack(pady="400", padx="60")
root.mainloop()
```

Thank you

Comment: When the window appears, use your mouse to stretch it vertically and the label will appear. Otherwise reduce the `pady=` value.

Comment: It is because `pady="400"` is too big to fit into a window with height of `544` pixels. So the text is squished to zero height.

Comment: You asked this question in Python chat room, right? and you got the solution as well

Comment: yup I got the solution! @PSSolanki

Comment: Good to know that :)

Comment: :D ..................................................